# in clojure symbols are functions, why?

Tags: clojure, symbols

In clojue I can invoke a symbol as a function:

```clj
('sym 1 2) => 2
('sym 1) => nil
('sym 1 2 3) => ArityException
```

What's the point? how are symbols as functions used in clojure?

Answer (score 1):

Symbols as function behave the same way as keywords behave.  They work
like `get` and are used for lookup.

```
(println ('+ {'+ + '- -}))
; → #object[clojure.core$_PLUS_ 0xe3cee7b clojure.core$_PLUS_@e3cee7b]
```

The 2-arity version, like `get`, provides is for providing a fallback, in case
the symbol is not a key where you look it up.  Since Clojure is very lenient
with inputs, you will just get back `nil` (or the default `2` in your first
example as default) for `1`, which does not support looking things up by key.

Comment: As described in the manual: https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Symbols

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. What's the use case though? With keywords it is clear, keywords are tags of data, so you say get me data by that tag. Symbol is a named pointer that points to a var (location) that has value. How is that a data selector?

Comment: @Sharas Keywords and symbols are both a form of *interned strings* and in fact, the Keyword implementation is based on the Symbol implementation. In Clojure, typically any Clojure value can be used as a key in a map, but interned strings like Symbol and Keyword are particularly efficient for this purpose. Keywords, however, are more common as keys in maps than symbols. Symbols are typically used for other things. Because of their suitability as keys in maps, it is practical that they both have the interface of a Clojure function.

Comment: @Sharas vars are vars. Symbols are much closer to keywords. A place where you usually deal with symbols is in macros or if you write "compilery" stuff. You will see this features as rarely used like `:syms` destructuring in your day-to-day code bases.

Answer (score 1):

Symbols are used to lookup values in maps where the symbol itself occurs as a key. It can be used like this on a map:

```
('a {'a 2 'b 3})
;; => 2

('a {'b 3})
;; => nil

('a {'b 3} 119)
;; => 119
```

Don't be afraid to look at the [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java#L127) of the `Symbol` class. It has two methods that implement the [IFn](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/javadoc/clojure/lang/IFn.html) interface. The `IFn` interface is implemented by Clojure functions. Here is the implementation of two `invoke` methods of that interface inside the `Symbol` class:

```
public Object invoke(Object obj) {
    return RT.get(obj, this);
}

public Object invoke(Object obj, Object notFound) {
    return RT.get(obj, this, notFound);
}
```

Pay attention to the occurrence of the `this` keyword in the code above, which is the symbol itself passed as *key* argument to the [clojure.lang.RT.get](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java#L758) method in order to lookup the value from a map.

In fact, the Symbol class implements the `IFn` interface indirectly through the [AFn](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AFn.java) abstract class as seen [at the top](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/AFn.java#L15) of the `Symbol.java` file: `public class Symbol extends AFn`.

*What is the point?*
**Answer:** Convenience, brevity. You could just as well call the [get](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1496) function to lookup a symbol in a map:

```
(get {'a 2 'b 3} 'a)
;; => 2
```

Remember that in Clojure you can typically use any Java object as a key in a Clojure hash map as long as it implements the `.hashcode` and `.equals` method. Symbols are a form of [interned strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) and are therefore very efficient to lookup. Because of their suitability to use as keys in a map, it is natural to implement the `IFn`interface for convenience.

Another class that is related to `Symbol` is [Keyword](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Keyword.java) which is also a form of interned string. The `Keyword` class is in fact based internally on the `Symbol` class.